# Android Studio 0.4.3 Eclipse project without gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, eclipse-adt, android-gradle-plugin

Prior to this version it seemed easy to open an eclipse project as-is in Android Studio without any conversion. I prefer the Android Studio environment, but am working on a project that uses eclipse as the main IDE. I'd rather not have to download the eclipse bundle just for this one project.

Is there any way to open an eclipse project as-is, without conversion to the gradle build system, in Android Studio 0.4.3?

EDIT:
It appears that if you use Android Studio's download from source control feature, it'll let you open the project that way. But what if I already have the source downloaded? I don't want to remove it just to redownload it again. It seems like this option has disappeared from the main 'import' wizard.

Comment: Then i think you should start using Intellij Idea with ADT Plugin. which will support both type of Android projects. It is made for that only.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to move to Android studio entirely one day, so I don't want to switch to intellij's base ide.

Comment: Check my Answer, I don't feel good to write long strings in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're strongly encouraging users to move toward the Gradle build system, and we're in the slow process of making that the only way to create *new* projects in Android Studio -- you're seeing this now on importing Eclipse-based projects. We'd like to replace all other build systems in use with Gradle, including Ant and the Eclipse internal builder, though the latter two are farther out on the roadmap.

If your ultimate goal is to move to Android Studio, then you might want to reconsider and just set up a Gradle build file. You don't have to adopt the Gradle-style multimodule project structure (which the current Eclipse importer imposes upon you by making a copy of your project); you can rework your **build.gradle** file to use the Eclipse-structured project in-place. You can get a good start on this if from Eclipse you use the feature to export your project to Gradle build files. It will set up the project in that fashion, though that feature in ADT is a little out of date and you'll need to update the version of the Android Gradle plugin in the build file and the Gradle version in the wrapper that it outputs.

I think this may actually solve your problem. IntelliJ or Android Studio have never been able to use the Eclipse project directly -- they've always imported the Eclipse project and converted to an IntelliJ-style project, and if you later change the Eclipse project, you'll need to re-import into IntellilJ-land. I'm guessing your real desire is to use the Eclipse project in Android Studio without having it make a copy and converting into its preferred directory structure. (By the way, we'll eventually improve Eclipse-to-Gradle import to lift this restriction).

Once you have the Gradle build file in place, you can use it when working with the project in Android Studio, and you'll still have the Eclipse project files when working with it in Eclipse. The big drawback is that you'll have to keep them in sync as you change dependencies and project structure, but hopefully that doesn't happen too often. Even if you weren't using Gradle, you'd still need to keep both projects in sync anyway, so Gradle isn't costing you anything there.

Having said all that, it doesn't directly answer your question, which is how to use the your project without Gradle.

Once you have an IntelliJ-built project, you can open it in Android Studio and use it normally without migrating to Gradle (though I think it does show you a popup when opening the project recommending you do so; you can ignore that). What you need to do is to get that initial IntelliJ project, and once you have it, check all the **.iml** files into source control -- those **.iml** files contain all the project information. To get those files, you'll need to import the Eclipse project either in IntelliJ CE, or in Android Studio prior to 0.4.0. Then you'll have your **.iml** files -- hang on to them.

I'll point out that if you're using Gradle as your build system, we recommend that you ***don't*** check those .iml files into source control. There, the **build.gradle** files are the source of truth for project structure; the fact that Android Studio creates .iml files at all is an implementation detail that reflects that internally Android Studio is still treating this project as an import instead of deriving structure from the Gradle files directly (and we resynchronize state when we know we need to). But saving those **.iml** files into source control or modifying them directly will lead to confusion or loss of any changes you make there when it resynchronizes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Scott. If I'd known that I could use gradle and eclipse side by side as you describe, and still be able to build from both, I'd have asked the question in a  manner more related to that topic. I'll have to look into doing that. Thanks for pointing me in that direction. If you have any further advice, feel free to drop it here.

Comment: Nice answer. Although I really like Android Studio I'm having really big issues in using it since my team prefers Eclipse. Too bad it makes it difficult to work in multiple environments. I used the workaround to clone project from git source, then I got the "old" setup.

Comment: Gradle wouldn't be so bad if the path to my code were shorter than: `MyApp/app/src/main/src/com/mywebsite/myapp/AnActivity.java`. Seems like someone's idea of a joke.

Comment: Gradle uses a lot of memory, but a lot. Why are you **encouraging** developers to use gradle? And why does it need sooooo much memory?

Comment: The problem with gradle is it panics and start cursing, if you put it in a computer without network connection; And if you do put it in a computer with a network connection, it starts copying files all over place and things go out of hand. My team of 4 uses android studio and as soon as they open IDE, my network gets congested. 90% of requests are originated from Gradle and Android studio and there is not even a single clear document to tell me how to make them work in a TOTALLY OFFLINE environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give a try to Intellij Idea with ADT Plugin instead of Android Studio, if such requirements are there. Intellij IDEA will support both type of Android projects.

What If I want to move to Android Studio completely sometime?

There is nothing new in Android Studio it is just an IDE based on Intellij IDEA. You can easily switch between Intellij IDE and AS anytime. The only thing is to learn in AS is the new  gradle build system. IDE related most of the features are there in Intellij IDE as well.

If you want to move Android Studio start using gradle Build System. That is only the main power of new Tools.

As per your question you don't wanna move your project in gradle then you can have both IDE together like Intellij IDEA at place of Eclipse and Android Studio as well. Msot of the Developer including me having Eclipse along with Android Studio.

**EDIT :**

I found a workaround to import Eclipse project in Android Studio but I will not recommend you to do this

Look at my answer here

[Not Use Gradle In Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506119/not-use-gradle-in-android-studio/21506291#21506291)