# Not Use Gradle In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded to the latest release of Android Studio and it no longer recognizes `.iml` files as projects. Previously, importing an Android project from just sources would create just an `.iml` file but now it creates a whole bunch of Gradle files which is really annoying.

Is there a way to get Android studio to not use Gradle and just `.iml` projects?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is based on Intellij Idea in which .iml files are "IntelliJ IDEA Module" file which contains all information about module's its dependencies in the projects, each module will have its own .iml file which is a part of project structure in Intellij. Where build.gradle files are for building your application using gradle build system.

In AS 0.4.3 a lot of improvements are done for importing and converting eclipse project automatically in Gradle which doesn't allow to import eclipse project as it is.

I found a workaround to do this please follow the steps

- Create a new folder/directory
- Move your Eclipse project inside it
- Now from import option in AS select the newly created directory instead of direct eclipse project directory.

Studio will give you a suggestion to move the project in Gradle as soon as it is done with import, don't do that.

But I strongly recommend you to start using gradle build system.

Have a look in to the Scott's explanation here :

[Android Studio 0.4.3 Eclipse project without gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421248/android-studio-0-4-3-eclipse-project-without-gradle/21422342#21422342)